# Getting the group id from a modern team site

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online, microsoft-graph-sdks

I have a SharePoint modern team site with an associated group. I have the url for the site. I need to get the groupid from that url. Is that possible with Microsoft Graph?

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$filter=mailNickname eq 'modernsitename'&$select=id
```

Comment: I only have the url :( Not the group name.

Comment: Suppose your url like sites/yoursite, just replace "modernsitename" as "yoursite".